Scaled Relative Graph Analysis
The drug concentration levels $c_1$ and $c_2$ in two compartments are modeled by the following differential equations:
$V_1\dot c_1=-\rho_1(c_1)-\alpha_{12}c_1+w_1$
$V_2\dot c_2=-\rho_2(c_2)-\alpha_{21}c_2+w_2$ ,
where $c_i \geq 0$ are drug concentrations, $w_i$ are exogenous inputs, $V_i > 0$ are volumes, $\alpha_{ij} > 0$ are flow rates, $w_i$ represent exogenous inputs and $\rho_i$ are degradation functions which each obey an incremental sector condition
$\lambda_i\leq\frac{\rho_i(x_1)-\rho_i(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}\leq\mu_i$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in \Re$, where $0 < \lambda_i \leq \mu_i$. Drug concentration in the body is modeled using the positive feedback interconnection of the two compartments, given by the equations:
$w_1=\alpha_{21}c_2+u$
$w_2=\alpha_{12}c_1$ ,
where $u$ is an external drug dosage.
Consider the system at rest at time $t = 0$.

How would one go about analytically deriving a Scaled Relative Graph (SRG) from $w_i$ to $c_i$ for a single compartment, considering the parameters $\alpha_{12}, \alpha_{21}, \lambda_1$, etc.? Additionally, what observations can be made regarding the passivity and gain properties of this operator?

In the context of a positive feedback interconnection, how can an SRG be analytically derived for the system treating $u$ as input and $c_1$ as output? Furthermore, could you share your thoughts on the gain and passivity properties from $u$ to $c_1$?


